# Trying to Combine 2 Google Sheets tabs into one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to use the Query method for this as it needs to be updated automatically whenever new data appears on either sheets.

Here is what I have so far, but it says: "Query completed with an empty output"

```
=query({IMPORTRANGE("GOOGLE_SHEET_URL", "Bing!A2:J"); IMPORTRANGE("GOOGLE_SHEET_URL", "Google!A2:J")}, "select * where Col1 <>''")
```

Comment: Please provide the URL for a view only sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this function:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Sheet1ID","Bing!A1:J");IMPORTRANGE("Sheet2ID","Google!A1:J")},"select * where Col1 <>''")
```

Instead of adding the full spreadsheet URL, I've used the sheet ID on the IMPORTRANGE functions:

**Example**

From:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iw7uryewre-sdfkjhdfjkdsjh-sdfkshdjfhdsdkfhd/edit#gid=0
```

To:

```
1iw7uryewre-sdfkjhdfjkdsjh-sdfkshdjfhdsdkfhd     **<----- the "Sheet ID" after d/ on the Sheet URL**
```

**Result:**

Main test Spreadsheet file:

[image]

Test Spreadsheet 1 file:

[image]

Test Spreadsheet 2 file:

[image]

**NOTE**:

Actually, using full sheet URL should work just fine on [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en). However, there could be some typo in your Sheet URL or sheet name inside of your IMPORTRANGE function which you may want to double check.

Comment: Thanks, I tried again and turns out the first column being a date was the problem. I tried the same "select * where Col2 <>''" and it worked.